# Regexp to find the lenght of string which starts with a number

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

What should be the regexp to find the lenght of string which starts with a number.I have tried like `([0-9].*){5,}` this and its not working.

I want to check if the string starts with a number and its length greater than 5

Comment: Can you add some sample inputs

Answer (score 0):

> check if the string starts with a number and its length greater than 5

You can use this regex:

```
\b\d\S{5,}
```

**Regex Breakup:**

```
\b     - word boundary
\d     - match a digit
\S{5,} - match any non-space character 5 or more times
```

In Java regex would be:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d\\S{5,}");
```

Comment: Should be 4, not 5, since the initial digit counts too.

Comment: Right but OP wrote `length greater than 5` that means valid input input should be at least 6 in length

Answer (score 0):

You don't require to put ".*". It means match any successive repetition of it.

Just try for [0-9]{5,}

Comment: Only matches 5 or more digits. `1abcd` should match too, since it *"starts with a number and its length greater than 5"*.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to check if the string starts with a number and its length greater than 5

So, first character must be a number: `[0-9]`
And it must contain at least 4 more characters for a total of 5: `.{4,}`

```
if (text.matches("[0-9].{4,}")) {
    // YAY
}
```

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tB7jU4/1) for demo.

Answer (score 0):

`([0-9].*){5,}` is almoost good but u are looking for :
 `[0-9]` a number 
 
`.*` any character 0 till endless times 
 this at least 5 times

if u chance it to `[0-9].{5,}` u get the following:
`[0-9]` any digit 
`.` any character 5 or more times

u can chance the `[0-9]` to `\d` then u get `\d.{5,}`
add `\b` in front to make shure its the start of a word then u get the following:
`\b\d.{5,}`